# Upload Video to GAE Blobstore and Get Input While Uploading

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video, blobstore

I am am using Google App Engine in Python and I want users to be able to upload a video, which is functioning properly by following their [basic example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Complete_Sample_App) but then I want to be able to get the user to add additional information about the video, like the title and category and a summary while it is uploading.  Is there any way I can make the upload asynchronous so that the user doesn't have to wait the whole time the video is uploading?

I know about the create_upload_url_async() method but that doesn't do what I am trying.

Right now I have the following which uploads and serves but I want to make an intermediate step where the user can add the info preferably on the same screen as the UploadHandler while it is uploading.

```
class VideoHandler(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):      
        user = self.get_user()
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/uploadingvideo')
        self.render('videohandler.html', user=user, upload_url=upload_url)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key))
```

I'd be glad to provide more information if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

this has been troubling me alot too clifgray. the solution is to build your form around the blob form.

Here's google's example on how to submit data to the blob store.

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Just remove the self redirect bit at the bottom of the code and add some code to handle your form.

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]

greeting = Greeting()

if users.get_current_user():
greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
greeting.video = str(blob_info.key())
greeting.content = self.request.get('content')  
greeting.put()
```

Your form in your django template should look something like this:

```
form action="{{ upload_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">

textarea name="content" placeholder="write something about this video.."  tabindex="1" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

input name="file" type="file" >

input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />

/form>
```

There you have it. hope this helps